# Skype Camera not working in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, video, skype, webcam

my camera is not working in skype. I tried to use:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

which led to the following error message (skype started anyway):

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD
  cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

I also tried

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

which result in skype starting but video not working anyway.

I use Ubuntu 15.04 with a BisonCam NB Pro, its driver is uvcvideo and its working fine (tested with Cheese). Skype version is 4.3

Any Ideas how i can get camera in skype working?

Comment: Can you please provide us a snapshot of Skype -> Options -> Video Devices?

Comment: Wow it is just working. Problem was you cannot enable video while the person you are calling has not answered yet. Thanks for your input :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot enable video until the person you are calling has answered. The button is just grey.

Anyway to test your video in skype one has to check Skype -> Options -> Video Devices and see whether there is a video showing up.